# How shall I name two tables in latex?

Tags: tables

I wrote the following table:

```
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c}
             $\bigoplus$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
             \hline
             0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
             1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0\\
             2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1\\
             3 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
             4 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
        \quad
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c}
            $\bigodot$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
            \hline
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
             1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
             2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3\\
             3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
             4 & 0 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

I want to name my first table 9.1 and second table 9.2
How can I do that please help

Comment: You have to wrap your `tabular`s in `table` environments, and add a caption (and maybe a label for future reference)

Comment: \Welcome to ReX.SE! Like `\begin{table[htb] \caption{caption text}\label{tab:a}        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c} ...`

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{8}  % for this example only
\section{tables}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption 1 text}
    \label{tab:a}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c}
             $\bigoplus$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
             \hline
             0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
             1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0\\
             2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1\\
             3 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
             4 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
        \hfill
     \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \caption{Caption 2 text}
    \label{tab:b}
    \centering
       \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c}
            $\bigodot$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
            \hline
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
             1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
             2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3\\
             3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
             4 & 0 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```